# Views Display Mode Toggle

Tags: 7, views

I'm looking for a way to add the ability for users to toggle one of two view modes. Essentially, looking for a 'list/grid' switch. I've tried using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_modes but it's failing to switch the URL at all.

If anyone has knowledge of a patch/fork of this project, or a way to achieve this, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Have you looked at the issues list for that module? Perhaps the patch you are looking for is there?

Comment: I'm actually just going to use a jQuery cookie. I did find a patch, but with its current support, I don't really want to risk it.

Comment: Ok, well be sure to post your code as an answer when you're done :)

Answer (score 1):

Display Suite Extras module (part of [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)) has an option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating two separate views, each set the way you want and a link as Global Text in the header of each that directs to the other.

Comment: Interesting. And how would you ajaxify that switch?

Comment: ajax? :)  If that's the feel you want, I would create the two views, and use a custom tpl to show them, with some simple jquery to act as a switch, hiding one and showing the other. Both would load at page time but then there's no delay during the switch.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. I didn't mention Ajax in the question because I didn't ask it :)) it was just a comment cause I was thinking about a similar feature. .. you might complete your answer